# [C#]Составить запрос к ютубу

Tags: c#, request, youtube

Нужна помощь в создании такого запроса к ютубу

Все данные для запроса есть, осталось только составить его, отправить и получить ответ.
Есть такой набросок запроса, только без передачи параметров, также есть одна загвоздка, заключается она в том, что если раскрывать context, то там ещё миллион миллиардов каких-то параметров.

```
        string mail = "";
        string apiKey = "токен";
        HttpWebRequest requ = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create($"https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/channel/reveal_business_email?key={apiKey}8&prettyPrint=false");
        requ.Headers.Add("сюда параметры: id канала, а потом капча");
        HttpWebResponse respa = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        using (var reader1 = new System.IO.StreamReader(responsa.GetResponseStream(), encoding))
        {
            mail = reader1.ReadToEnd();
            reader1.Close();
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine(mail);
```

параметры строки запроса:
key=AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8&prettyPrint=false

Запрос сведений о полезной нагрузке:

```
{"context":{"client":{"hl":"ru","gl":"RU","remoteHost":"91.243.107.129","deviceMake":"","deviceModel":"","visitorData":"Cgt2Vl9Jd2Jicm5KdyjH0IeVBg%3D%3D","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.160 Safari/537.36,gzip(gfe)","clientName":"WEB","clientVersion":"2.20220602.00.00","osName":"Windows","osVersion":"10.0","originalUrl":"https://www.youtube.com/c/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%AF%D0%BB%D0%B0/about","platform":"DESKTOP","clientFormFactor":"UNKNOWN_FORM_FACTOR","configInfo":{"appInstallData":"CMfQh5UGEJje_RIQ1IOuBRCUj64FELfLrQUQgo6uBRC4i64FEOCjrgUQmOqtBRDXmq4FEJiHrgUQkJOuBRCR-PwSENi-rQU%3D"},"userInterfaceTheme":"USER_INTERFACE_THEME_DARK","timeZone":"Europe/Moscow","browserName":"Chrome","browserVersion":"100.0.4896.160","screenWidthPoints":768,"screenHeightPoints":1014,"screenPixelDensity":1,"screenDensityFloat":0.8999999761581421,"utcOffsetMinutes":180,"connectionType":"CONN_CELLULAR_4G","memoryTotalKbytes":"8000000","mainAppWebInfo":{"graftUrl":"https://www.youtube.com/c/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%AF%D0%BB%D0%B0/about","pwaInstallabilityStatus":"PWA_INSTALLABILITY_STATUS_CAN_BE_INSTALLED","webDisplayMode":"WEB_DISPLAY_MODE_BROWSER","isWebNativeShareAvailable":true}},"user":{"lockedSafetyMode":false},"request":{"useSsl":true,"internalExperimentFlags":[],"consistencyTokenJars":[]},"clickTracking":{"clickTrackingParams":"CC8Quy8YACITCP6aopSwoPgCFRJlmwodcmoB2g=="},"adSignalsInfo":{"params":[{"key":"dt","value":"1654777930087"},{"key":"flash","value":"0"},{"key":"frm","value":"0"},{"key":"u_tz","value":"180"},{"key":"u_his","value":"7"},{"key":"u_h","value":"1080"},{"key":"u_w","value":"1920"},{"key":"u_ah","value":"1040"},{"key":"u_aw","value":"1920"},{"key":"u_cd","value":"24"},{"key":"bc","value":"31"},{"key":"bih","value":"1014"},{"key":"biw","value":"753"},{"key":"brdim","value":"-1920,69,-1920,69,1920,63,1918,1034,768,1014"},{"key":"vis","value":"1"},{"key":"wgl","value":"true"},{"key":"ca_type","value":"image"}]}},"recaptchaResponseToken":"03AGdBq24c67v1yqvjRzbn8jHK8ucn33NTprO19s_kGSOf7nOc3Yet8gE4nb9j--vVma889ZX6tI6_EBo3cjqAS6C4XSKxm-Ozb7BEBgmYSKirj-z2xw5qHpXvfAWqlWc89rHpDkeWZQ88Jm8wXQvzRnx1GbGW-IOqG8vNvQOjhprj0JmE088hNB9_-vFZEcAIVIKjaFeyC7UTrE1AU6QJudCnHgx8g3zI39kTt8ePMAMwo5Pm3VVnAuzOVJvsYrCqQmB9lAe8XtqyGFO91_hrxLu3tobheDzPWFUpbZLRDCSCC8hHbACt-gxu-varMDhSmilm9FlBcHt8jutNeCNT8n9uLD-tK4TL-q1DHbr6yoiNVn2hDGUbLAK9vIyiESrN2UhXp-4cnsH56HeNDCTQhy_aWUQ0QhdvLFuaqnYwaYrKSDdtH8KXtB0zxKo7F9qY7bvBDAioJ3eYuKKh3g7Z5n-WUxqvCZVEsQ","channelId":"UCTcnAmNuA2WTySV9VCQfWiw"}
```

Comment: Забыл сказать, чтобы получить все эти запросы в нетворке, надо зайти на канал, нажать на "О канале", а дальше просто нажать: "Показать адрес электронной почты", пройти капчу, нажать "отправить".

Comment: Пробовали сделать через Google.Apis.Youtube.v3? (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.YouTube.v3/) Никогда не работал с этой библиотекой, но вдруг это поможет как-нибудь

Comment: Смотрел эту библиотеку, ничего полезного(для данного софта) там не нашёл

Comment: `HttpWebRequest` устарел очень давно. Закопайте это ископаемое обратно.

Comment: `Забыл сказать` не пишите дополнительную информацию в комментариях. Вопрос можно редактировать, а комментарий удалить.

Comment: В заголовках что? В теле запроса что? Тип запроса какой? На скрине нет этого ничего.

Comment: тип запроса POST, остальное, не знаю как сказать, кидать кучу скринов бессмысленно. Специально оставил инструкцию, как получить этот запрос, для тех, кто хочет помочь

Comment: @hr1st1337 Скрины вообще не нужны, есть заголовки запроса, переключите в необработанный вид, получится текст, текст можно вставить в пост с вопросом.

Comment: @aepot Поменял, посмотрите на обновлённый вопрос

Comment: Уберите скриншот, вставьте только нужную вам часть в виде текста

Comment: скриншот убрал, но что это поменяло? за день решения нет